# When a specific css style is very often used, should it be a own class?

Tags: html, css

When I need very often a specific style like `float: left` is it better to make a own class or put this style in every class where it is needed?

Here is a example page for what I mean.

[JS-Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/h8buxf02/)

Is it good how the class `left` is used? Or would it be better when I put every `float: left` style into the other classes?

Comment: Either is fine. Voting to close as off-topic due to it being opinion-based.

Comment: I agree, if it works for your situation, go for it.

Answer (score 5):

The things to consider are readability and repeating yourself.

Readability:

Having a `left` class with the only rule as `float: left` will help to make your HTML more readable. Because whenever someone see that class on an element, they know it will be floated left. So in that way it improves readability.

DRY:

With CSS the old adage of "don't repeat yourself" is almost impossible to adhere to, but I think it should still be considered. In this case you should compare.
How many times will I add `float: left` in my CSS? versus How many times will I add `class='left'` in my HTML?

I would note that most CSS frameworks use utility classes like `.left{float:left;}`

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a matter of opinion but I'd argue that no, you shouldn't.

HTML and CSS exist separately because they address separate concerns. HTML represents the information and CSS represents how that data should be displayed.

Creating classes containing only one rule starts to blur that distinction and starts to introduce style-specific information into your HTML.

Say you want to change all your stuff that was floated left to be floated right. You could either change your CSS rule to something like

```
.left {
   float: right;
}
```

which is obviously horrendous or else you'd have to go into your HTML and change the class in every situation you wanted to change the value of the float - not ideal either. In a perfect world, you want to be able to make styling changes ONLY by editing the CSS. That's what it's there for. Obviously sometimes this just isn't possible but a lot of the time it is *if you marked up your HTML in a semantically meaningful way*.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with doing that.

I create css helper classes for myself all the time.

When you're not using a framework like bootstrap it really helps to be able to add `class="border"` your html to quickly see what's going on in the box model

Answer (score 1):

There are many opinions on top of this, 
depends on your context...

In Sass there are **placeholder selectors**, [you should have a look on how they work](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors)

Other way is creating **helper classes**, [an example could be the **pull-left** implemented in bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp)...

A simple class that does just one thing in order to be reusable everywhere in your code...

The first solution increases the output css file, the second, instead, increases the html file...

Maybe the secondone could be better that the first.